# Some sites work, some don't

Tags: windows, internet, home-networking

I'm having some internet connection problem - some sites (thankfully superuser is included) work perfectly while others (like www.boardgamegeek.com or www.couchsurfing.com)  do not work at all. The problem exists in 3 different browsers and does not appear in other computers in my network (Edimax wired router).
Can you help solve the problem?

Comment: Are you on a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not using a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boardgamegeek! haven't seen that in ages!... Anyway..

Not sure why it would be blocked, but the first thing to try is to take a look at your hosts file - c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts  Do you see any entries other than localhost?

Just incase of bad caches, close all internet browsers and go to the command prompt, type the following to clear your DNS cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Next, I would check for firewall / antivirus settings and make sure that nothing is being blocked.

Lastly, if you are still having problems, double check your internet settings to see if you are going via a proxy server that may have been incorrectly set up.

Comment: Your answer wasn't exactly it, but close- I had a wrong dns server in the connection settings. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that for next time an issue like this comes up - I wonder why some were working and some were not :S

Comment: I'd guess the inaccessible ones weren't covered by the primary DNS, so had to fall back to the incorrect secondary DNS?

Comment: I suppose we can only really guess, but +1 as a reasonable explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue for 3 different browsers, could your firewall be blocking something?

What firewall are you using? Is it configured to block sites based on content? (parental lock for example?)

Comment: No firewall on my computer. The router firewall I didn't check, but since it doesn't happen on other computers, and I have not set any computer specific rules, I guess it's not to blame.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems that you fixed your issue, I had a similar issue previously on a work machine that wasn't fixed this way and forced me to re-install TCP/IP.  For Windows, instructions and an automated solution can be found at [Microsoft's Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357).  Maybe this answer will help others too.