# Cannot access some websites

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I am experiencing a rather odd problem. I cannot go to some internet sites like ucla.edu, microsoft.com or samsung.com

What happens is that the sites start loading elements (sometimes they don't) and then just keep loading forever. When I ping these sites, either I get "timed out" or "general failure". I managed to narrow down the problem to the Windows installation as rest of the computers in this network can go to those sites with no problems. Additionally, I hooked up my phone's internet to this computer and it acts the exact same way. The rest of the internet and the computer in general work fine.

What I've tried:

- All kinds of antimalware scans - they didn't find anything except for a few tracking cookies
- Various browsers (I am usually on Opera)
- Changing DNS as well as flushing the cached DNS data and other temp files on both Windows and browser - when pinging the addresses do return the correct IP anyways
- Checked out the hosts file - it's clean
- Fiddling with the MTU - tried lower values to no effect (other computers in the network use 1500 with no problems)
- connecting to the sites though a proxy, they work through a proxy. So, I am assuming that this Windows installation can't connect to the IP addresses rather than the web addresses
- I have no software firewall; the hardware firewall also applies for other computers in the network which have no problems
- tried fiddling with internet security/privacy options (even though I don't use IE), no effect

The Windows in question is Win7 SP1 with all the latest updates. The problem started out around a month ago but i haven't had the time to deal with this until now, the windows installation is around 1 year old. I really do not want to resort to a reinstall since last time it took me a whole day to get all my programs installed and the rest of the week to remember all the custom settings everywhere...

I can see some nifty malware that somehow slipped through targeting microsoft or samsung but ucla? Other than a freak corruption of a windows setting somewhere, this makes no sense

Comment: It sounds based on what you describe is your installation is beyond saving.  It sounds like you have an malicious infection designed to keep you infected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system.
2. Update definitions and run a complete virus scan. An additional free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.
3. Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the [System File Check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833). When it is done, reboot.
4. Flush your DNS as suggested in this answer; [Some sites work, some don't](https://superuser.com/a/57844/97028)

Comment: I'd add a strange problem we had a few weeks ago: everything worked correctly, but not websites in france. Our provider confirmed us a problem with the main link with that country

Comment: I already did run malware bytes and spybot scan (with updated definitions). I cant do the eset scan since apparently its one of the sites i cant visit. SFC reported no violations. I also already flushed the dns.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the TCP/IP? - [How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)

Comment: Posting links to microsoft.com is kinda useless for me but yes i've tried it

Comment: Sorry. Assumed you were using another of the computers on the network to access this. Have you tried another user account on this PC to see if your user account is corrupt?

Comment: The other computers arent mine so i cant really use them, i made a new user account and tried it there but same issue. I also downloaded eset antivirus and offline updated it and it just finished scanning and found nothing.

Comment: By chance, has the driver for your network card been updated or corrupted? Can you roll it back to a previous driver? Windows Update may have changed something. How about System Restore back to a time when it worked properly?

Answer (score -1):

Please try  [hotspotshield](http://www.hotspotshield.com/) if the sites are loading well , then you dont have problem with whole  windows settings which means you have problem with Internet Service Provider might be temporary network issue.